# How to autoload helper functions in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I just downloaded CodeIgniter 4 from their official GitHub. They changed a lot from CodeIgniter 3. I want to use `base_url()` function in the view and for that, you need to load URL helper and in CodeIgniter 3 I autoloaded it in `config/autoload.php` file. But now they have entirely changed the structure of `config/autoload.php` file in CodeIgniter 4 and it is very confusing to me.

You can still use the `base_url()` function in your views in CodeIgniter 4 by using below code in your constructor of controller `helper('url');`

If anybody who used CodeIgnter 4 knows how to autoload helper functions like url by modifying `config/autoload.php` file please help me.

Comment: too early to use CI 4

Comment: @AbdullaNilam yes I know it sir. I am just trying the upcoming version to understand its new features not for doing any projects on it as they don't recommend Cl 4. Since Cl 4 is not yet officially released I don't get any help from 3 party sites.

Comment: just i have to say wait for it. :)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam oke sir..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CodeIgnter 4 is currently in developing phase so many features are still not available. The answer is you cannot autoload helpers or libraries in autoload.php file in codeigniter 4.

I know this is a feature used by many of us but autoloading every thing will decrease site performance so may be developer team decided to drop this feature.

**from Codeigniter 4 Documentation:**

> You can load your helpers in your controller constructor so that they become available automatically in any function, or you can load a helper in a specific function that needs it.

https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 6):

Add your helper to the array in `BaseController.php` file like this:

```
protected $helpers = ["form"] // BaseController.php:29;
```

Comment: How to load library ?

Answer (score 3):

Just add name of helper(s) you want to load in

`protected $helpers = []` in

`/app/Controllers/BaseController.php`

CodeIgniter4 will load those helpers automatically.

For example:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ['cookie','date']; // <=== this
```

Answer (score 2):

### For Future Reference

Since there is no autoload in `autoload.php` you have to load all helper files by itself. Unlike global load in CodeIgniter 3.

**How to load**

```
public function FunctionName()
{
    helper(['form', 'validation']); # before retun to view.
    #rest of your code
}
```

**Do we need to load this into each and every method(s)?**

Yes. Since I play around it I'm unable to load helper file globally.(2018-2-07)

Comment: Now we can load the helpers globally via BaseController.php

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Create helper on *App/Helpers*. Example : *alert_helper.php*, **MUST** ending with **_helper**

[image]

[image]

**Step 2**

Load helper on Constructor or Method. `helper(['alert']);`

[image]

**Step 3**

Use helper

[image]

**DONE**

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment that helpers need to be named with the _helper suffix. I had a bug caused by me not knowing this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE CodeIgniter 4.3+

**CodeIgniter 4.3.0** has finally added this feature.
Just edit the **app/Config/Autoload.php** file and add the helpers you need globally.

```
public $helpers = ['repository_helper', 'serializer_helper'];
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html#auto-loading-helpers